# Quota limits for YouTube Android Player API

Tags: android, youtube-api

I would like to use the [YouTube Android Player APIs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) in an new Android app. Can you shed some light on what the free usage limits are for this API? I am interested in how many videos can be played per day before hitting the free API limit.

I have already done some background research and here is what I know:

1. The Android Player API uses the YouTube app and the YouTube Data APIs v3 to play videos.
2. The programmer must supply a Data API v3 key which tracks usage.
3. Access to the Data APIs v3 is limited to 5 million units per day per app.
4. Different operations via the Data APIs v3 carry [different costs in terms of units](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota).

As far as I can see, the YouTube app is in control of placing requests to the Data API. How can I compute the reads / writes / updates, etc that the YouTube app uses on my behalf when I don't have the source code? And how can I translate these operations into units and then into actual videos? Videos are what I care about and what I can actually control via the Android Player API.

Let's take the video for Baby by Justin Beiber as an example. It is 3 minutes 45 seconds long and its id is kffacxfA7G4 and full URL is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kffacxfA7G4. What would it take in units to play this video if I supplied the id to the Android Player API as the starting point? How many different such videos can be played via the API per day?

EDIT: This question is largely directed at the people on the YouTube API team @ Google (like https://stackoverflow.com/users/385997/jeff-posnick) who use the `youtube-api` tag on StackOverflow for tech support. See this blog post for details: https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2012/09/the-youtube-api-on-stack-overflow_14.html

Comment: After using android Youtube api to play video, I see my quota request is always 0. It just increases when I use the api to retrieve video's information. Seems that just playing video doens't count on api's quota

Comment: I don't notice any quotas changing when I use this Android api for playback. Nothing changes at `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/quotas?project=YOUR_PROJECT_ID`. Are you sure that there are limitations for playing videos?

Answer (score 0):

> Usage and Quotas. YouTube may, in its sole discretion, set a quota of
>   operations on Your YouTube API usage. You shall not attempt to
>   circumvent automated use-quota restrictions.

from: https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms

And that means that you simply don't know what the quota is, if there is a quota, and basically it's a unilateral choice if your app will live or die.

I should also remind the fact that commercial solutions are likely to break this kind of license or they are not a good solution at all simply because you are going to offer a product when you have no power over it.

I also highly suggest to read the **API Use** and **Prohibitions** sections.

Comment: Thanks for your response... you raise some interesting points. Regarding the quota, based on the API console that manages access to the API, I see that the current quota is 5 million units per day... though you are right that per agreement that can be changed at any point. But even so, I would like to understand what the unit costs are for video playback so I can estimate costs if usage is exceeded.

Comment: I don't notice any quotas changing when I use this Android api for playback. Nothing changes at `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/quotas?project=YOUR_PROJECT_ID`. Are you sure that there are limitations for playing videos?